# Error after running $ sudo npm install error is - Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, npm-install, sudo, failed-installation

I am running the hyperleder fabric IBM marble-blockchain example. After running

```
$ sudo npm install
```

I am getting an error:

```
npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kundankumar/.npm/_logs/2019-06-19T07_41_32_817Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What node version and npm version are you running? It does say it's not an npm problem, but almost everytime we see this problem, it's a version issue.

Comment: NPM tried to run the grpc@1.10.1 install script and failed.
Maybe looking at /home/kundankumar/.npm/_logs/2019-06-19T07_41_32_817Z-debug.log will help you to have a clue of what happened

Comment: try running `npm rebuild`

Answer (score 0):

try running `npm rebuild`. I had a similar error and it was because of some stale c++ object files that node was using